# UIPopoverController dismiss on 'tap off' - how do I detect this event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I am using a UIPopover on my navigation bar. I have several UIBarButtonItems and the popover extends from one of these.

When the popOver is activated I changed the style of the button to `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`.

However, the popOver is dismissed by tapping off the UIPopoverController as expected, but upon this I want to change the style back to `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`.

Is there a way I can detect if the UIPopOverController is closing? And therefore piggyback this for my own needs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Implement the [`-popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307-CH1-SW4) method in your `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` and you should be able to do what you need to do in there.

```
- (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController {
   //do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: THANKS! you've saved me hours of head-scratching. Cheers

Comment: Hiya, is there somewhere on the web where these types of methods are plainly visible? All i want to see is a list of methods that can be triggered by certain actions on the UI, sort of like Events to Event Handlers in .net apps.

Comment: For some reason, this is not firing for me, is there something obvious I have missed? i.e how is it attached to the popOver to know which delegate or method to call?

Comment: IbrarMumtaz, did you set the UIPopoverControllerDelegate for this popover? When you create the popover, be sure to set its "delegate" property to the object that created the popover...and be sure to specify <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> with the @interface declaration for the class that creates the popover.

Comment: This is deprecated as of iOS 13 and has been replaced by `presentationControllerDidDismiss`.