# How to detect the exact event that dismisses UISearchDisplayController upon tap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

As far as I know, an active `UISearchDisplayController` can be dismissed under two conditions:

1. When the Cancel button is clicked anytime
2. When the search textfield is empty AND the gray dimmed area under the search bar is
   tapped.

I was able to detect case 1 trivially via the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method. As for case 2, there doesn't seem to be any delegate methods that I can use to get notified **immediately** upon a tap.

I implemented all the delegate methods to study the sequence of invocation and found that for case 2, only two methods were fired:

Tap -->  `willUnloadSearchResultsTableView` --> `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`

However, both events are fired only after a delay from the tap and not upon the immediate tap event (the latter is something I really need).

For completeness, the following is a sequence of events for case 1:

`searchBarCancelButtonClicked` --> `willHideSearchResultsTableView` --> `didHideSearchResultsTableView` --> `willUnloadSearchResultsTableView` --> `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`

Any ideas?

This answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212988/uipopovercontroller-dismiss-on-tap-off-how-do-i-detect-this-event) suggests using `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`, but for my case it comes too late. For the curious, what I am intending to do is to **immediately** reset the search text value to a previous value upon a search cancellation. Implementing this logic in `willUnloadSearchResultsTableView` or `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` causes a rather unsightly flicker in the search bar when the text is set only after a delay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:
1.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

this method is invoked by searchBar that UISearchDisplayController composite.
[But you need to define when to return YES/NO (hides first responder) very accurate.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210809/901508)

P.S. perhaps you need to assign delegate of searchBar to self.

2.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
```

is always invoked from both cases.